# MySQL select having count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "keywords" which looks like:

```
keyword_id | domain_id | keyword
    1      |     15    | some_word
    2      |     29    | aaa
    3      |     15    | bbb
```

...and so on.

I want to have a single mysql query which selects all "keyword_id"s if count(domain_id) is more than 100. Put simply, if some domain_id (let's say 15) has more than 100 records in "keywords" table, I want to get all keyword_id records for this domain.

After searching this site for similar questions, I decided to use this one:

```
SELECT keyword_id FROM `keywords` HAVING COUNT(domain_id) > 100
```

But it doesn't work. This query simply returns absolutely ALL the rows from table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group your results by `domain_id`

```
Select keyword_id from `keywords` where  domain_id in(
SELECT domain_id
FROM `keywords`
GROUP BY domain_id
HAVING COUNT(domain_id) > 100);
```

Comment: I need to select keyword_id, not domain_id. Even if I change this query to select keyword_id instead of domain_id, phpmyadmin still displays the same - Showing rows 0 - 24 (1886 total, Query took 0.0020 sec)

Answer (score 3):

You just need a `group by`:

```
SELECT keyword_id
FROM `keywords`
GROUP BY keyword_id
HAVING COUNT(domain_id) > 100;
```

Comment: I tried using exactly the same query. In BOTH cases phpmyadmin returns exactly THE SAME:

 Showing rows 0 - 24 (1886 total, Query took 0.0010 sec)
 
 Showing rows 0 - 24 (1886 total, Query took 0.0020 sec) 

P.S. 1886 is the total number of rows.